# Running a macro in excel 2013 every time workbook opens or closes

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to run a macro every time an excel files opens and before it closes. I've tried using the below script but it didn't work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
'my macro
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? Your script doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Put MsgBox("Hello World!") in, as David mentioned. Marked as "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: @DavidPostill I've written `MsgBox("Hello World!")` but nothing appears when I open the workbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I run a macro every time a workbook opens or closes?

Opens:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
' dosomething
End Sub
```

or

- Use `Sub Auto_Open()` in a module

---

Closes:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
' dosomething
End Sub
```

or

- Use `Sub Auto_Close()` in a module

---

Sources:

- StackOveflow question [what is a good way to autorun macros upon open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406979/what-is-a-good-way-to-autorun-macros-upon-open)
- [VBA code to run a macro prior to closing an excel file](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/243781-visual-basic-applications-code-run-macro-prior-closing-excel-file.html)